# Store custom object in NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

In my app, I perform some asynchronous calls which return me some jsons. I parse these responses and I populate some structs, like the following:

```
public struct StudentInfo {

let availableExams : Int?
let course : String?
let courseLength : Int?
let department : String?
let enrolledExams : Int?
let name : String?
let surname : String?
let registrationDate : String?
let studentClass : String?
let studentId : String?

init?(json: JSON) {
    self.availableExams = "availableExams" <~~ json
    self.course = "course" <~~ json
    self.courseLength = "courseLength" <~~ json
    self.department = "department" <~~ json
    self.enrolledExams = "enrolledExams" <~~ json

    let auxName: String? = "name" <~~ json
    self.name = auxName?.firstCharacterUpperCase()

    let auxSurname: String? = "surname" <~~ json
    self.surname = auxSurname?.firstCharacterUpperCase()

    self.surname?.firstCharacterUpperCase()
    self.registrationDate = "registrationDate" <~~ json
    self.studentClass = "studentClass" <~~ json
    self.studentId = "studentID" <~~ json
}
}
```

I would like to use the `NSUserDefault` to store these objects, in order to retrieve them in the case in which no internet connection is available to perform the API call to the external web service. Is this a viable option, or there are simpler way to do it?

Comment: First, don't use `NSUserDefaults` as a database. Second, convert the data to a JSON string and store this.

Comment: look into [NSKeyedArchiver / NSCoding](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)

Comment: I retrieve data through an Alamofire request as json; then I use Gloss in order to parse the json into this struct object. Can I use `NSUserDefault` to store the json response from Alamofire before to parse it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use those functions to do what you want...

```
+ (id)getUserDefaultsForKey:(NSString *)key{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key]];
}


+ (void)setUserDefaults:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value] forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

+ (void)deleteUserDefaultsForKey:(NSString *)key{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Try once...but your custom object should follow like those functions below.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];

    [coder encodeObject:self.property forKey:@"property"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        self.property = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"property"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Use those 2 functions in the custom object and then save that object using above functions in user defaults.

Comment: How I can adapt my object to use the `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` functions? Please could you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: just use those two functions and put your property names where its written "property". And same for other properties. All properties of the class.

Comment: and also you have to subclass nscoding in the .h file like if your custom class name is CustomClass then it will be like CustomClass : NSObject<NSCoding> in the .h file interface declaration.

Answer (score 2):

To save a custom object on disk you have to make that object confirms to conforming to NSCoding. But a struct can not confirms to NSCoding.
We can add a class within the StudentInfo struct that conforms to NSCoding:

```
struct StudentInfo {
let course: String
static func encode(student: StudentInfo) {
let studentClassObject = HelperClass(student: student)
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(studentClassObject, toFile: HelperClass.path())
}
static func decode() -> StudentInfo? {
let personClassObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(HelperClass.path()) as? HelperClass
return personClassObject?.student
}
}
```

.

```
extension StudentInfo {
class HelperClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

var student: StudentInfo?

init(student: StudentInfo) {
  self. student = student
  super.init()
}

class func path() -> String {
  let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first
  let path = documentsPath?.stringByAppendingString("/StudentInfo")
  return path!
}

  guard let course = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("course") as? String else    {     student = nil; 
 super.init(); 
 return nil 
 }

  student = StudentInfo(course: course)

  super.init()
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
  aCoder.encodeObject(student!.course, forKey: "course")

    }
  }
}


let me = StudentInfo(course: "Swift",)

StudentInfo.encode(me)

let myClone = StudentInfo.decode()

firstNameLabel.text = myClone?.course
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your data and store it in core data rather than NSUserDefaults for efficient memory management, You can get your data back from your database (Core Data) without having any issue of internet connection. Store your data as transcend data in your database.